# How to always have positive value for a coefficient in polynomial curve fit in fit() using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a polynomial fit for the following function. I want the coefficient "p003" to be a positive value for all time. Is there any option that can be used to set that constraint on p003 in gnuplot?

I have tried setting p003 >= 0, but this results in a syntax error.

```
h1(x,y,t) = 1/(p000+p100*x+p010*y+p001*t+p200*x*x+p020*y*y+p002*t*t+p110*x*y+p011*y*t+p101*x*t+p003**2*t*t*t);
fit h1(x,y,t) "data.txt" u 1:2:3:5:(1) via p000,p100,p010,p001,p200,p020,p002,p110,p011,p101,p003;
```

Edited version after @Ethan's comment.

```
h1(x,y,t) = 1/(p000+p100*x+p010*y+p001*t+p200*x*x+p020*y*y+p002*t*t+p110*x*y+p011*y*t+p101*x*t+s3**2*t*t*t);
fit h1(x,y,t) "result_mutual_-1_-1_0.15_0.25_0.2_0.85_0.2_-1_0.098_0.098_0.098_JBE_JW.txt" u 1:2:3:5:(1) via p000,p100,p010,p001,p200,p020,p002,p110,p011,p101,s3;
p003 = sqrt(s3);
```

Edit: Describing the problem

In the equation, x and y are set to a specific value. So the h1(x,y,t) becomes h1(constant1, constant2, t). Then we plot the values of h1 as t varies. 't' here is distance, and t>0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your function and fit in terms of a dummy parameter (`s3**2`) and afterwards set p003 = `s3**2`.

To clarify:

```
h1(x,y,t) = 1/(p000+p100*x+p010*y+p001*t+p200*x*x+p020*y*y+p002*t*t+p110*x*y+p011*y*t+p101*x*t+ (s3**2) *t*t*t)
fit h1(x,y,t) "result_mutual_-1_-1_0.15_0.25_0.2_0.85_0.2_-1_0.098_0.098_0.098_JBE_JW.txt" u 1:2:3:5:(1) via p000,p100,p010,p001,p200,p020,p002,p110,p011,p101,s3
p003 = s3**2
```

The down-side of doing it this way is that the covariance and error estimates reported for s3 would have to be appropriately corrected to be applicable to p003 itself.

Comment: I edited the code. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: So, for some dataset I get s3 to be negative values. It's back to the same problem again.

Comment: For some data set, I get s3<0 and p003 = sqrt(s3) which gives imaginary number.

Comment: does squaring s3 actually square the value of s3 in the equation?

Comment: I actually think p003 = s3^2. If s3 is a negative number. and I am using s3^2 in the equation, p003 = s3^2.

Comment: See edited answer. Yes I meant to set p003 = s3^2 afterwards, not sqrt(s3).  Sorry for typing faster than I was thinking.